# How to show an image in Xcode Playground with NSImage

Tags: swift, xcode

I can actually preview my image when I click on the eye in the side bar. However, the last line in the code doesn't show anything.

```
//: A Cocoa based Playground to present user interface

import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
var topLevelObjects : NSArray?

let imgView = NSImageView(frame:NSRect(x: 0, y:0 , width: 300, height: 400))
imgView.image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/Users/me/Code/MyPlayground.playground/Resources/image.png")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imgView
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Project Navigator to left side
2. Select Resources folder
3. Right click then "Add files to 'Resources' "
4. You can use like that -> imgView.image = UIImage(named: "image_name")

   [You can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnytM.jpg)